# In SQL server can we add a not null constraint to an existing column of type varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Alter table Products alter column prodName varchar not null**

I just want to make **prodName** column as Primary key. As I haven't specified it as not null, I want to add not null constraint to it now and then make it as Primary key.

Comment: Sure this is possible. What have you tried? Of course this won't work if you have a NULL in any row. You will first have to ensure there are not any rows with NULL.

Comment: yes, there are no NULL values in the column. But I'm confused about the syntax. Is that correct syntax, when we use varchar?

Comment: If you trying to alter column and add `NOT NULL` statement to `NULL` column, you also have to set default value: `DEFAULT('')`.

Comment: A default is not a requirement of a NOT NULL column.

Comment: You can do this with the following. alter table sometable
alter column prodName varchar(25) NOT NULL

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, it is not required in case you manually change `NULL` values or delete all records. But on existing table it is easier just set `DEFAULT` value.

Comment: The point is that adding a default has more implication than this one time change. I would argue strongly that a primary key column should NOT have a default, it should always be provided by any query.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, You are right. Anyways,there is no need of setting the field to DEFAULT value here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for altering the column so it is `varchar(1)` is:

```
 Alter table Products alter column prodName varchar not null;
```

You should *always* specify a length with character types in SQL Server.  Something like:

```
 Alter table Products alter column prodName varchar(255) not null;
```

Before doing this, set the `NULL` values to something else:

```
update table
    set Products = ''
    where Products is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to specify the varchar with length, which I have missed in the Query that was Posted. Now I can add not null constraint and make it as Primary key.